# How to have dynamic values for queryParams in ember 2.17

Tags: ember.js

I have a route where I want one of the params to be the first date of the previous month.

To do so I need to be able to dynamically set the start_date.

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['start_date'],
  start_date: "AAAAAA"
});
```

I tried to do it in the `setupController` :

```js
setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('start_date','BBBBBBBBB')
  }
```

But this is not correct :

1) it ignore a param passed via the URL. I want my dynamic value to act as a normal query param

2) The value of params in the `model()` is from the controller.

How can I have a synamic value (first day of last month) as the default value of a route's params ?

Comment: Did you tried setting it in `init` hook of `Controller`?

Comment: Do you have the param defined on your route?

Comment: Do you want the default value to show up when a user visits the route with no value like `/someroute?start_date=01012019`? Or do you just want to use a default value if there is no value set so the URL would look like `/someroute` but your code would use the `01012019` date?